# Value change but UI don't

Tags: flutter

I want to show a button only if the new value is different from the old one. But its not working, the button isn't showing

```
class ViewPatientPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int status;
  final String name;
  const ViewPatientPage({required this.status, required this.name, super.key});

  @override
  State<ViewPatientPage> createState() => _ViewPatientPageState();
}

class _ViewPatientPageState extends State<ViewPatientPage> {
  String name = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    name = widget.name;
  }

  SizedBox space() {
    return const SizedBox(height: 15);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
           (name != widget.name) ? TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'Editar',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )): const SizedBox.shrink()
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              space(),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: widget.name,

                // keyboardType: keyboardType,
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val.toString().isEmpty || val == null || val == '') {
                    return 'Fill field';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    label: const Text('Name'),
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  name = value.trim();
                  print(name);
                  print('widget ${widget.name}');
                },
                // inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
              ),
              space(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton
random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton
random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton
random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton
random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton
random text to satisfy the site's rules flutter code vscode button textButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setState()` in `onChanged`.

Something like:

```
onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            name = value.trim();
          });
          print(name);
          print('widget ${widget.name}');
        },
```

Comment: Cant imagine how I forgot it lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call setState inside onChanged function
`setState(() { name = value.trim(); });`

Comment: Cant imagine how I forgot it lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To update the UI, you have to a call a `setState()` in the    `onChanged: (value) {}`

```
setState(()
{
...

});
```